# Minha JTable não atualiza quando adiciono uma row [Resolvido]

Tags: java, jtable

Eu tenho uma JTable na minha MainForm que recebe os dados de um form em outra janela só que depois de receber os dados a JTable não atualiza.

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement psm = null;
String cod = txtCod.getText();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE cod = "+cod;
String nome = null;
float valor = 0;
String desc = null;
try{
    conn = DatabaseConnection.MysqlConnection();
    psm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    psm.execute();

    ResultSet result = psm.executeQuery(sql);

    while(result.next()){
        nome = result.getString("nome");
        valor = result.getFloat("valor_m2");
        desc = result.getString("descricao");
    }
    if(txtHeight.getText().equals("") && txtWidth.getText().equals("")){
        float a2 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(rootPane, "Por favor insira a área da peça", "Área", HEIGHT));

        float valorm = a2 * valor;

        MainForm mf = new MainForm();
        mf.addInTable(cod, nome, a2, valor, valorm);

        this.setVisible(false);
        psm.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    else{
        float alt = Float.parseFloat(txtHeight.getText());
        float lag = Float.parseFloat(txtWidth.getText());

        float area = alt * lag;
        float valorm = area * valor;

        MainForm mf = new MainForm();
        mf.addInTable(cod, nome, area, valor, valorm);

        this.setVisible(false);
        psm.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex);;
}
```

Aqui ele vai criar a pesquisa e mandar para a JTable no MainForm

```
public void addInTable(String cod, String prod, float area, float prec, float precTot){       
String nom = prod;
String con = cod;
String are = Float.toString(area);
String pre = Float.toString(prec);
String tot = Float.toString(precTot);

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblMain.getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[]{con, nom, are, pre, tot});

float total = 0;
total = total + precTot;


lblTrue.setText(Float.toString(total));
```

E aqui ele adiciona os dados na JTable. Só que como eu disse ele não atualiza a tabela e não mostra os dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que entra nesses laços condicionais da sua classe DAO ele cria uma nova instancia de MainForm e manda os dados por isso não da certo.

Tente criar uma classe que tenha todos esses atributos que você deseja retornar e então na sua classe DAO crie um método como por exemplo:

```
public List<EssaClasseVolta> findAll(){
}
```

e lá no seu mainFrame você cria uma lista e da um get nesse metodo.
Logo depois é só popular usando for para percorrer a lista.

Comment: o problema não e popular a tabela e sim adicionar na tabela meu amigo me apontou o mesmo fato do mainForm criar uma nova instancia. Mas eu já consegui arrumar, mas mesmo assim muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.